# Symfony2: should ACL be applied to child entities aswell?

Tags: symfony, acl

I have this entity structure:

```
Apartment -> Floor (one to many)
Floor -> LeaseTerm (one to many)
```

I'm applying ACL to Apartment entity on persist (owner).

My question is, should i bother applying ACL to Floor and LeaseTerm entites aswell, or should I just use their relation to Apartment to check ownership of LeaseTerm and Floor entities?

My purpose is restricting the user from editing/deleting/viewing other peoples Floors/LeaseTerms.

Edit: I posted a similar question [here](http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=40010) but haven't gotten real answers.

If the question is unclear let me know - I'll explain further. But I think I covered the main idea.

Comment: I think the answer on the similar question post is pretty good! Indeed, it depends on how you access and edit your child entities (Floor and LeaseTerm). Do you plan to edit them independently, or will they always be in a context of Apartement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if all floor and LeaseTerm have the same access of Apartment apply ACL to the topmost entity if not apply ACL to all entity